# Using conversion specifier n correctly

Tags: c

When I run the program below with input `1X` it prints `1 2` but when the input is `0X` it prints `0 32765` instead of `0 2`. How come?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int x;
    int charCount, matchCount;

    matchCount = scanf("%xX%n", &x, &charCount);
    if (matchCount == 1) {
        printf("%u %d\n", x, charCount);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My be worthile reading the manual page for [scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: @user3121023 In the application I'm working on I need to read hexadecimal values.

Comment: Then how do you expect `0X` to work?

Answer (score 3):

The `scanf` `%x` specifier reads in a hexadecimal integer which is (and this is the key point) ***optionally preceded by 0x or 0X***! (See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).)

Your second example doesn't give an actual value to `x` (or, possibly gives it zero for blank input after the `0x`)! Try using, say `1F` and `0F` as input tests.

*PS: The value of `32765` looks suspiciously like a phoney conversion from `-1`.*

Comment: But shouldn't *matchCount* be zero in that case?

Comment: Possibly. Maybe `scanf` is reading a blank value for `x` and interpreting it as zero?

Comment: The `%n` conversion doesn't happen because `scanf` has already consumed the `X` with `%x` and doesn't match it after. Hence `charCount` remains at its uninitialised value. Better to initialise it to zero first and if it is zero after, it means `scanf` didn't reach the end of it's format string.

Comment: @Graeme Does this mean that `%x%nX` is well defined? In that case I can use *charCount* + 1.